# Is it possible prediction of chemical activity with few data?

Tags: svm, predictive-models, neural-networks, chemometrics

I have activity data (represented by a real number) for five chemical compounds (and for which I have a set of 600 descriptors) and would like to use neural networks or SVM or any other system that would allow to predict activity data for new related compounds. Most people tell me that with only 5 compounds, all methods will fail, since one needs more data, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much hope, unless you can dramatically reduce the size of the problem. Assuming I understand correctly what you imply about the modelling situation when you refer to '600 descriptors', if you were talking about working with a single descriptor (or single *a priori* measure based on several of them), and that described the behavior very precisely, you might almost get away with a small number of cases.

But with many such descriptors, I don't see how there's any possibility of saying much of anything with only five data points.

Comment: and what if I know the 10 most representative descriptors?

Comment: I still don't see how to do anything reasonable with fewer than many dozens of points, unless you can narrow it further.